# how to fectch oracle spatial SDO_GEOMETRY as com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry using hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, spatial

How to fectch oracle spatial SDO_GEOMETRY as `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry` using hibernate session?

I have one Geometry parameter as below

I want to fetch the geom field from the database(only geom field not the entire object)
I need to get this geom as com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry

I am getting the below error while fetching using HQL

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002

I have configured the dialect correctly
`org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect`

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
@Entity
@Table(name="STG_C_COUNTRY")
public class StgCCountry implements Serializable {

    private Geometry geom;

    public void setGeom(Geometry geom) {
        this.geom = geom;
    }
    public Geometry getGeom() {
        return this.geom;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with and let me know :

```
...
@Column(columnDefinition = "SDO_GEOMETRY")
private Geometry geom;
...
```